# systemd "socket activation" vs xinetd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, xinetd, socket-activation

I use `xinetd` and it works for my purposes. However I recently discovered that systemd has something built in called "socket activation".

These two seem very similar, but systemd is "official" and seems like the better choice.

*However before using it, are they really the same? Are there differences I should be aware of?*

For example, I want to start some dockerised services only when they are first requested - my first thought would be to use xinetd. But is socket activation better / faster / stabler / whatever?

Comment: If both work, use what you are comfortable with.

Comment: @RalfFriedl Good advice, but I'd rather use what is more official/standard - it seems to me that would be socket activation. However I can't find info anywhere stating whether they actually do the same thing, I don't want to run into any problems.

Comment: According to the `systemd` crowd, `systemd` should be used for everything. `xinetd` won't cause you any problems. With `systemd` you have to write two files, a `.service` file and a `.socket` file. Both approaches will work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don’t think systemd socket activation is significantly better than `xinetd` activation, when considered in isolation; the latter is stable too and has been around for longer. Socket activation is really interesting for service decoupling: it allows services to be started in parallel, even if they need to communicate, and it allows services to be restarted independently.

If you have a service which supports `xinetd`-style activation, it can be used with socket activation: a [`.socket` description](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html) with `Accept=true` will behave in the same way as `xinetd`. You’ll also need a `.service` file to describe the service. The full benefits of systemd socket activation require support in the dæmon providing the service. See [the blog post on the topic](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/inetd.html).

My advice tends to be “if it isn’t broken, don’t fix it”, but if you want to convert an `xinetd`-based service to systemd it’s certainly feasible.

Answer (score 5):

You can use either `xinetd` or `systemd` for socket activation, both will work. I personally find `xinetd` easier to use because everything is in one file, but have also used `systemd` because it is more flexible, especially with listening on multiple addresses and socket forwarding to UNIX sockets and not just to IP sockets.

Here as an example I used to forward TCP connection to the MySQL file socket:

/etc/systemd/system/mysql-proxy.service

```
[Unit]                                                  
Description=MySql Proxy Service
Requires=mysql-proxy.socket

[Service]
Environment=MYSQL_PROXY_TARGET=/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/mysql-proxy
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-socket-proxyd ${MYSQL_PROXY_TARGET}
```

/etc/systemd/system/mysql-proxy.socket

```
[Unit]                                                  
Description=MySql Proxy Socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=192.168.1.1:3306
ListenStream=192.168.2.1:3306
NoDelay=true
FreeBind=true

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Traditional forwarding needs `Accept=true`, `systemd` aware processes are supposed to handle multiple connections in one process or fork additional processes as required.